# What is the technical term or name for pop-up menu for seeing profile?

Tags: interaction-design

May I ask if somebody knows what is the name of the pop-up menu when the user clicks on the profile? There are many interface techniques and I would like to improve the interface for the existing project I am working on.

[image]

Comment: Didn't you just call it by it's name, though? I don't think there's much more to it than being a slightly more specific version of a generic "Pop Up Menu".

Comment: I am wondering if there is some technical term for it. What do you mean by call it by its name though please?

Comment: I just meant that "pop up menu" is already the name that you used, I wouldn't make it any more complicated :)

Comment: "pop up menu" is a behavior and not a menu name.  I would call it "user menu"

Comment: @xaa, thank you. "behavior" and "names" are different terms. I agree with you. May I ask if any reading resource is available to learn about behaviour, names and other terms?

Comment: I don't have specific suggestions but you may like the abookapart.com and mashingmagazine.com books. I found them very well written and instructive.

Comment: @xaa, thanks again. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**At its essence, It's a [card](https://material.io/components/cards/#behavior) that contains user profile info. Its called a User Card or User Profile Card presented in a popover and triggered by mouse hover/touch/click.**

Many designers and Design Systems consider it a variation of the card component.

There is a lack of naming standards. Since there is no consensus, there are many fancy names out there. Some of them are:

- UXSE calls it a [Flair](https://stackoverflow.com/help/flair) and [User Card Popup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104810/how-does-the-user-card-popup-work?__hstc=188987252.64e374f08e1656ca25bd61b2a093abbd.1576824252686.1579684998143.1580403416504.8&__hssc=188987252.1.1580403416504&__hsfp=2637435193) on Mouse Hover
- Hero Image Card by Hubspot [Canvas](https://canvas.hubspot.com/components/containers)
- [Raised Card](https://semantic-ui.com/views/card.html) by Semantic UI
- [Cards](https://www.bbc.co.uk/gel/guidelines/cards#accessibility) by BBC Gel

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

there is really no agreed general semantic term for this interface component.

Shopify regards it as a **[Popover menu](https://polaris.shopify.com/components/overlays/popover#section-best-practices)** in their Polaris Design system.

IBM regards to it as an [**Overflow menu**](https://www.carbondesignsystem.com/components/overflow-menu/code/) in their Carbon Design system

The Ant Design system refers to it as a **[Popover menu.](https://ant.design/components/popover/)**

Bootstrap refers to it as a **Dropdown menu.**

I personally think it's an **Enhanced Popover.**